# SLDS - Cannot add class for toast notification theme

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, slds

I have a toast notification and I'd like to add slds-theme--success and slds-theme--error to them based on success or failure of data entry.  The adding and removing classes in JQuery are not working.  Any ideas on how I can add and remove those classes?

**Visualforce**

```
<div class="slds-notify_container" id="notify" >
    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify--toast" role="alert" id="notifyColor">
       <span class="slds-assistive-text">Info</span>
       <button class="slds-button slds-notify__close " title="Close">
           <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large" aria-hidden="true">
               <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
           </svg>
           <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
       </button>
       <div class="slds-notify__content">
           <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small" id="success">Component Added!</h2>
           <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small" id="fail">Category and Component Required</h2>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function notificationToast()
    { 

        var prod = document.querySelector("[id$='product']");
        var cat = document.querySelector("[id$='category']");

        if ( $("[id$=product]").val() != '' && $("[id$=category]").val() != '' && $("[id$=app]").val() != null){
            $('notifyColor').addClass('slds-theme--success');
            $('notifyColor').removeClass('slds-theme--error');
            $("[id$=fail]").hide();
            $("[id$=success]").show();
            $("[id$=notify]").fadeIn(500, function(){ $("[id$=notify]").slideUp(500); } );            

        }else{
            $('notifyColor').removeClass('slds-theme--success');
            $('notifyColor').addClass('slds-theme--error');
            $("[id$=success]").hide();
            $("[id$=fail]").show();
            $("[id$=notify]").fadeIn(1000, function(){ $("[id$=notify]").slideUp(1000); } );            
        }   

    };
```

Comment: jQuery uses CSS selectors (you need to add a "#" to the id, as in $('#notifyColor').

Comment: IN addition to that, I set it in the controller and use merge Fields and a rerender to handle the theme type. i.e. `slds-theme--{!themeType}` then set it in the controller based on what I need at the time and rerender the toast panel

Comment: I used the #sign and and I can get it to change it to "error" but it won't change to success.  If I start it at success then it will be in success until there is an error but it won't go back to success.  I'll give that them type a try now.

Comment: The {!theme} is too complicated right now.  I tried but really had to do a major refactor.  I don't want to risk it at this point.  I'm still having the issue of not being able to alternate.   Once red it stays red

Comment: it appears the remove class is not working.

Comment: code error (not surprising).  I only added hashes (#) to the else clause

Comment: if you post and answer I can mark it answered.